# Can't get WiFi Payloads to IPAD using Apple Configurator

Tags: ipad

I have 400 iPads I need to prep and am having a couple issues.  I was hoping somebody could give me a bit of advice..

**Question**

- How can I verity the WiFi payloads are copied to the iPad?

**Background**

- I received a backup config from the customer
- I also received their settings in case the restore didn’t work.
- Of the settings I’m concentrating on two to verify the restore worked, or a manual config and prepare worked.  Those are verifying an app was installed, and wifi payloads.
- When I restore using the supplied *.iosdevicebackup file neither the app or the wifi settings are on the iPad
- I config’d ITunes for the customers account -> downloaded the app -> imported into the Apps tab of the Configurator program and now get that loaded, but I can’t confirm the wifi payloads.
- I have 3 wifi payloads configured in the setup tab -> wifi section.  2 are for the customers wifi and the 3rd is for our in-house wifi just for sanity’s sake.  Each are configured with ssid and WPA / password, but when the IPad is restarted after the prepare I would assume I would see all 3 networks and the iPad would connect to our in-house network automatically as it's the only one available.  But I only see a list of available networks, and I’m asked for a password when I try to connect to our in-house one.  I thought that was what the payload was for.
- I also tried making a profile and setting the wifi payloads up there, same result.
- I’ve been speaking with the local apple store, and while polite and professional, not much help..
- When I try to do a manual prepare my settings -> Restore value is Don't resort backup.  If I have that set to the backup I received I get an error when trying to customize the device at the end of the update.
- I also tried only 1 wifi payload, our in-house WiFi.  Same results.  I'm asked for a login / password when I try to connect.

thanx

Comment: I think this may be better asked at http://apple.stackexchange.com/, since I can't see the programming related part of the question.

Comment: OK- thank you I'll do that now.